# How do I persist data in memory with .net rest api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to C# rest API, I have a collection of data that is created when the user POST data into my REST api,
What is the best way to keep this data in memory ?
The data is stored in a c# collection.
I do not have a database to store this day, it must stay in memory for the life of the application.

I hope this is enough information for you guys to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve saving the data in many forms, but the most straightforward and trivial way will be using Database.

Here are few of the ways of storing information.

1. Install and use some kind of ORM to talk to your free *SQL Server Express* *MySQL server*. - Optimal, but required extra work installing and little to any plumbing.
2. Use *Redis* with *Nuget .NET Client*. - Optimal, but relays on external cache like server
3. Store the information at the AppDomain, like shown (how to get) similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763605/list-all-custom-data-stored-in-appdomain) - Dirty, and add information to Website RAM and damage performances
4. Save the information to a static or singleton class which will hold a dictionary for your information. - Add information to Website RAM and damage performances)
5. Save the objects into files. - Many files hard to handle